Can't enter passphrase for encrypted disk on splash screen
My Ubuntu laptop just upgraded from 6.8.0-49-generic to 6.8.0-50-generic.
With 6.8.0-49-generic, I could enter the passphrase on the splash screen during the boot process.
With 6.8.0-50-generic, the following happens:

The splash screen appears for 2 seconds, with a keyboard icon and the label "US" on the right of it. During these 2 seconds, I can enter characters.
Then the screen becomes black for 1-2 seconds.
Then the splash screen comes back, still with the keyboard icon but without the label "US". At this time, the keyboard is no longer responsive -- nothing happens when I press a key or enter.

I disabled the splash screen in GRUB settings, and I can enter the passphrase in the terminal.
At the same time the passphrase is requested, I can see the following messages:
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
Bluetooth: hci0: Mlaformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02

Any idea of what could be happening?
Thank you.
Vincent

The same problem. My advice - mark hold 6.8.0-49 kernel - this action prevents this kernel from deleted after update
sudo apt-mark hold linux-image-6.8.0-49-generic


the same happens for me. Also with 6.8.0-51.
So far I have to go to "Advanced options" and choose 6.8.0-49 manually.
It's definitely a bug, but I'm not sure in which component.

The same happens for me on an HP zbook running Kubuntu. I am not sure what happened in the last 48 hours, but this problem did not exist when I booted prior to today. You can get around the problem by entering the grub menu and going back to 6.8.0-49 as other mentioned, or you can select the recovery boot option to enter the password from the command line and then resume normal boot from there. Another interesting thing is that the text box for entering the password is no longer scaled correctly on the screen. It is larger than before.
